# IBM Websphere portlet classloader issue

Tags: websphere, portlet, websphere-portal

I am currently working on a portlet that is using the commons-collections jar file and am getting a NoSuchMethodError. To resolve this issue I need to change the classloader of my WAR file from PARENT_FIRST to PARENT_LAST (in the application.xml file).

However, when I do this my portlet will not launch and when I log into the console it displays the message "The portlet is temporarily disabled". If I change the classloader back to PARENT_FIRST then it will launch again but then I get the NoSuchMethodError.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: You need to investigate the logs to determine why "The portlet is temporarily disabled", and then someone can try to help solve that problem.

Comment: It will only be temporarily disabled in the scenario above, otherwise it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how, but today I started getting error messages in the logs when I was getting "The portlet is temporarily disabled". I was getting a java.lang.LinkageError which was down to the fact that I had the servlet-api-2.5.jar and a jaxb jar which was conflicting with webshpere j2ee.jar. Once I removed these dependencies and set the classloader to PARENT_LAST, it seems to work properly. It seems that a lot of people face similar issues. The link below is also useful http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?33663-dispatcher-servlet-quot-not-a-servlet-class-quot-in-websphere

Answer (score 0):

@MTH,

please try adding commons-collections as a shared library. See here for an example on how others have used shared library support [1]. That will give you the steps, just do it for the jars that you need to override/replace from WAS's classloader

[1] http://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/deployguide/deploying-jetspeed-to-websphere.html#section_4_2

thanks,
dims

Comment: The commons-collections jar I want to use at the moment is in a seperate utilities project and has been added to my portlets j2ee web module dependencies. This ensures that all of the libraries required for my project are in one place. I will try what you have mentioned above to see if it works, but do you know of a better fix because it seems that this could be a nightmare when deploying to different environments. I still dont understand why changing the classloader of my WAR from PARENT_FIRST to PARENT_LAST would break the portlet.

Comment: I have tried both methods in the link described above and although I do not get "The portlet is temporarily disabled" I still get the NoSuchMethodError so the class loader still seems to be doing PARENT_FIRST. Does anybody have any more suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any logs... but still, one of the most important things to look out for when setting your application to run `PARENT_LAST` is that your application isn't bundled with any system-level classes that may conflict with the ones provided by WebSphere Portal. For example, classes that pertain to the Portlet specification or the JavaEE specification.